# Find the solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a differential equation. I tried it many times but cant solve .

```
 xy'+(1+x)y=e^{-x}*sin2x
```

My solution 
After finding `F = e^p(x)dx` . It does not close in u.v form

[**Tried Solution**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0RHyHmdRczRSTBXX1FtSnBkU0k)

Comment: The right-hand side (after multiplying by $xe^x$) should be $\sin(2x)$. And since the derivative of $xe^x$ is $(x+1)e^x$, the left-hand side is $${d\over dx}[xe^x y].$$

Comment: oh yes you are right Many thanks